# Como puedo sacar el promedio de una columna de un JTable por medio de un boton en Java

Tags: java, array, jtable

Soy nuevo en esto de programar y me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para que unos datos que se guardan en un jTable temporalmente mas especificamente unas edades, hacerle el proceso de promediarlas y me aparezca el mensaje del resultado. Estoy trabajando por interfaz grafica por lo cual estoy estancado en el proceso de prograamar ese respectivo boton

Este sería mi codigo fundamental, solo no se como promediar la info de en este caso seria la tabla 4 (Edad)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrmPersona.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrmPersona.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrmPersona.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrmPersona.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new FrmPersona().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private void cargarDatos() {
    personas[index]=new Persona("Freddy","Mendez",123);
    personas[index].setEdad((byte)23);
    index++;
    personas[index]=new Persona("Maria","Garcia",234);
    personas[index].setEdad((byte)45);
    index++;
    personas[index]=new Persona("Juan","Perez",345);
    personas[index].setEdad((byte)15);
    index++;
    
    
}

private void limpiarCajas() {
    txtNom.setText(null);
    txtApe.setText(null);
    txtDoc.setText(null);
    txtCiu.setText(null);
    txtEdad.setText(null);
    txtDoc.requestFocus();
}

private void imprimirTabla() {
    String [] head = {"Documento","Nombre","Apellido","Ciudad","Edad"};
    String [][] datos = new String[index][];
    if (index>0) {
        for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {
            Persona p = personas[i];
            datos[i]=new String[]{""+p.getDocumento(), p.getNombre(), p.getApellido(), p.getCiudad(), ""+p.getEdad()};
        }
    }
    jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(datos, head));
}

private Persona [] personas=new Persona[10];
private int index=0;

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtApe;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtCiu;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtDoc;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtEdad;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtNom;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Esto serian los botones :

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String nom = txtNom.getText();
    String ape = txtApe.getText();
    String doc = txtDoc.getText();
    String ciu = txtCiu.getText();
    String edad = txtEdad.getText();
    Persona p = new Persona(nom, ape, Long.parseLong(doc));
    p.setCiudad(ciu);
    p.setEdad(Byte.parseByte(edad));
    if (index<personas.length) {
        personas[index]=p;
        index++;
        limpiarCajas();
        //jTextArea1.append(p.toString()+"\n");
    }
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    imprimirTabla();
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    for (int i=0; i<index-1; i++) {
        Persona p1 = personas[i];
        for (int j=i+1; j<index; j++) {
            Persona p2 = personas[j];
            if (p1.getEdad()>p2.getEdad()) {
                Persona temp = personas[i];
                personas[i]=personas[j];
                personas[j]=temp;
                p1 = personas[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    imprimirTabla();
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    for (int i=0; i<index-1; i++) {
        Persona p1 = personas[i];
        for (int j=i+1; j<index; j++) {
            Persona p2 = personas[j];
            if (p1.getApellido().compareTo(p2.getApellido())>0) {
                Persona temp = personas[i];
                personas[i]=personas[j];
                personas[j]=temp;
                p1 = personas[i];
            }
        }
    }
    imprimirTabla();
}
```

y este el boton que necesito programar :

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  /*byte t=0;
    double prom = 0;
    for (int  i=0;  i < index-1;  i++) {
        byte p = Byte.parseByte(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
        
        t+=p;
        prom=t%index;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "El prmedio es: "+prom);*/
}
```

Agradeceria de todo corazon quien pueda ayudarme

Comment: Por qué estás poniendo el dato de la edad como byte?

Comment: Me parecio el ideal, o alguna recomendacion?

Comment: usa un entero (integer), no te compliques. Recuerda mantenerlo simple